# Array queries give wrong answer

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation

I have a problem and I have no idea how to start, here it is:

> You are given a permutation of 1,2,...,n.
> You will be given q queries, each query being one of 2 types:
>
> Type 1: swap elements at positions i and j
> Type 2: given a position i, print the length of the longest subarray containing the ith element such that the sum of its elements doesn't exceed n
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line contains 2 integers n and q (1≤n,q≤105).
>
> The next line contains the n integers of the permutation p1,…,pn (1≤pi≤n).
>
> The next q lines contain queries in the format:
>
> Type 1: 1 i j (1≤i,j≤n)
> Type 2: 2 i (1≤i≤n)
>
> #### Output
>
> For each query of type 2, print the required answer.

Here is my code so far, but it gives me the wrong answer on the last few cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

long long atMostSum(int arr[], int n, int k, int a)
{
    int sum = arr[a];
    int cnt = 1, maxcnt = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        if ((sum + arr[i]) <= k) {
            sum += arr[i];
            cnt++;
        }

        else if(sum!=0)
        {
            sum = sum - arr[i - cnt] + arr[i];
        }

        maxcnt = std::max(cnt, maxcnt);
    }
    return maxcnt - 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int n, q;
    std::cin >> n >> q;
    int p[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        std::cin >> p[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        int a;
        std::cin >> a;
        if (a == 2) {
            int m;
            std::cin >> m;
            std::cout << atMostSum(p, n, n, m) << "\n";
        } else {
            int l, f;
            std::cin >> l >> f;
            int temp;
            temp = p[l];
            p[l] = p[f];
            p[f] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Sample Input

```
3 3
1 2 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
```

#### Sample Output

```
2
2
1
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include a complete set of code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Do you have any leads? Tell us what you've figured out so far and where think the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long long atMostSum(int arr[], int n, int k, int a){
    long long ans = arr[a];

    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
        long long sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            sum += arr[j];
            if(sum > n) break;
            if(i <= a && a <= j) {
               ans = max(ans, sum);
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

this isn't best for complexity but should be right...

Answer (score 0):

Cannot provide you with the complete solution, but something to get you started with. You are basically looking for a subset in arr[1...n] which consists of element arr[i] and a sum not exceeding n. So simply look for a sub-array with sum **(n - arr[i])** and then it becomes a classical problem of finding a ***subarray with given sum***

You can refer the later part of solution here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/